# PHP: why not is possible var var with $GLOBALS?

Tags: php

from https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

this work so cool:

```
$Z = ARRAY(1, 2, 3);
$H = 'Z';
print_r($$H);
```

then why this never work:

```
$Q = 'GLOBALS';
print_r($$Q);
```

Comment: If you are using it within function/method, then it's not possible to access superglobals https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php#81033

Comment: `function Justinas(){
 print_r($GLOBALS);
 }
Justinas();` get $GLOBALS and print it

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) states that it isn't possible to access superglobal variables that way:

> **Warning**
> Please note that variable variables cannot be used with PHP's Superglobal arrays within functions or class methods. The variable `$this` is also a special variable that cannot be referenced dynamically.